# Opening the custom file format in my application instead of downloading it on Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, file-association

When user type the url to my `.someExt` file in his web browser (on Android Phone), the message appears:

> This content is unsupported content. Do you really want to download?

Instead, I would like to associate the `.someExt` (my custom file extension) with my Android Application (that the user has downloaded previously) so when user type the url to `.someExt` in browser my Application will open the file.

How to achieve it? I guess it has to be done with manifest and some "handle" method in my Activity.

Based on: [Associate App with file extension - Intent filter Not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442925/associate-app-with-file-extension-intent-filter-not-working)

I have used:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>





        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/someExt" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="smb" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.someExt" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now, when user type the url to my `.someExt` the file is being downloaded and I can open it when downloading is done (so my Application will run it). But I don't want all those additional clicks - I want it to be:

1. User click the link to `.someExt` on the website.
2. The `.someExt` opens in my Android Application.

**And not the:**

1. User click the link to `.someExt` on the website.
2. The file starts to download.
3. User open "downloads" and click on downloaded file.
4. The `.someExt` opens in my Android Application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can realize this feature in Android with different kind of browsers. The URL user type is handled by the browser most of the time. How to deal with the scheme is decided by the behaviors of the browser. If your scheme is `http`, the browser will try to open with it own and handle by itself.

Currently, most browsers add support for `market` scheme. If the URI's scheme is `market`, it will jump to Google Play or other markets.

But is can be done from other app with `Intent`.

Declare your activity like following to receive the `ACTION_VIEW` action.

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="com.example.myapp"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.someExt"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

From other apps, you could do like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://com.example.myapp/test.someExt"), "*/*");
intent.setPackage("com.example.myapplication");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I don't want to do it from other app, but from browser and I certainly cannot code anything in it (mess with browser source code).